# Save button works fine in browser but can not save data to database

Tags: asynchronous, request

I am trying to create a save button that saves the task in a task list. After the data was saved, a request will be sent to the server that will enter the task into the database. The data the user entered appears fine on the browser, however the data was not saved until after the request, resulting in the data only being updated after pressing the button again. I suspect that this is due to the asynchronous nature of `useState`, but I can't figure out how to access the new data.

```js
const handleSaveClick = (id) => async () => {
    // Triggered when a task is edited and saved.
    let editedRowIndex = rows.findIndex((row) => row.id === id);
    if (editedRowIndex === -1) {
        return; // Handle the case where the row with the specified id is not found.
    }

    const updatedRows = [...rows]; // Create a copy of the rows array.

    if (updatedRows[editedRowIndex].isNew) {
        updatedRows[editedRowIndex] = { ...updatedRows[editedRowIndex], isNew: false };
        setRows(updatedRows); // Update the isNew property in the component's state.
    }
    setRowModesModel({ ...rowModesModel, [id]: { mode: GridRowModes.View } });
    const editedRow = (await editedRowIndex) !== -1 ? rows[editedRowIndex] : null;
    //console.log(editedRow)
    try {
        await axios({
            method: "PUT",
            url: "http://localhost:5000/api/editTask",
            data: editedRow,
        });
        // Request succeeded
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error making PUT request:", error);
        // Handle error if the request fails
    }
};
```